# I need to produce 144 unique numbers for array subscript with a formula that takes 2 numbers

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to find a formula for a function that can take two numbers, x and y, which each go from 1-12 (144 combinations) and will always produce a unique result.

The idea is that I'm making an array, `combotab[144]` where the formula produced by x and y produces a unique number to be used as an array subscript, which element will then hold a state `YES` or `NO`.

The sides in which x and y appear is important, so the x y combo cannot be equal to the y x combo.

Here is some code to create the combos:

```
int combotab[SIZE_NEEDED];

int create_combos()
{
    int x, y, j, z;
    y = x = 1;

    for (j = 0; j < 144; j++)
    for (x = 1; x <= 12; x++)
    for (y = 1; y <= 12; y++){
        if (combotab[FORMULA IN x AND y HERE] == YES){
            printf("Possible duplicate, find a better formula\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else
            combotab[FORMULA IN x AND y HERE] = YES;
    }
return 1;
}
```

Just to restate what I'm asking, I need to be able to go through every combination of `x` and `y`, where `y` goes from 1-12, and then `x` goes through 1-12, create a unique number based on those two numbers, which can be used as a unique subscript for the array. Each unique point in the array will hold a state: `YES` or `NO`. This means that I should have 144 unique `YES` states in my array by the end of this function.

(Notice that the variable `combotab[]` is global, so that all of the elements are initialized to `0` or `NO`.)

After this, I would create a function to get the states based on the number combos:

```
int get_combo_state(x, y);
```

This will return the state based on the combo given, but remember that the order in which the numbers appear does matter.

```
get_combo_state(10, 2) != get_combo_state (2, 10)
```

I tried this as a possible formula, but it didn't go too well:

```
(x * y + x + y + (x*x) / y) - y
```

This seemed easy because if x == 12 and y == 12 it's easy to see that all I would need is 168 array elements combotab[168].

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: have you tried something like (x-1)*12 + (y-1)

Comment: The easiest, if you may, is to change your `combotab` variable to be a two dimensional array, `int combotab[12][12]`. Then you can just access the information through `combotab[x][y]` if you have your `x` and `y` start from `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this to generate the composition:

```
int composed = 12 * (x - 1) + (y - 1); /*zero based*/
```

And recover the `x` and `y` using

```
int x = composed / 12 + 1; /*using integer division*/

int y = (composed % 12) + 1;
```

This idiom is common when working with arrays where the underlying memory is a single contiguous block. Zero-basing the composition simplifies the extraction arithmetic.

Comment: I'm not really following you, what do you mean by composition, zero basing, and extraction arithmetic? Where would I input these variables? All of this seems useful for future reference.

Comment: "FORMULA IN x AND y HERE" is "composed". The recovery formulas allow you to get the x and y values from "composed".

Answer (score 1):

What about `x * 12 + y`
(like `#define FORMULA(x,y) ((x) * 12 + (y))`)?

or better in your case `(x - 1) * 12 + y - 1` (it is not very usual to count from one in C language...)

//or the `x` and `y` swapped...

However, you I'd advise you to think a bit more about your design...

Answer (score 1):

What about making an array of the required size with elements `0` to `n - 1`, shuffle that array; and then use it to index into your `combotab`?

```
int indexarray[SIZE_NEEDED];
for (int k = 0; k < SIZE_NEEDED; k++) indexarray[k] = k;
shuffle(indexarray); /* writing shuffle() is left as an exercise to the reader */

//for (x...) {
//    for (y...) {
        if (combotab[indexarray[y * (ROW_SIZE) + x]] == YES) {
        }
//    }
//}
```